# Is this ants or termites?

Tags: termite

My tenant reported that ants have been digging dirt up between the cracks between house and sidewalk.

However, this seems to be quite a lot of dirt. Could it possible be termites causing this?

[image: image.png]

[image: image.png]

Comment: IDK but that's certainly *quite a lot of dirt*. But I'd assume w/e kills termites would kill ants and vice versa. And I don't see what a termite would find interesting below grade and next to a stone (?) foundation, and a real brick wall (?) that's not a facade over framing... unless you live in Australia (location ?)

Comment: AFAIK treatment for either would be same. They would drill holes around your the property and inject insecticide into the ground.

Comment: Ants, IMO.  Termites don't like light, that's why they build mud tunnels.  The ants are building a nest somewhere behind/under the brick.  And that's probably a brick facade, with an airspace between the back of the brick and the framing/insulating material.  My house is built that way.

Comment: While you're deciding on a long term solution, you could start by spraying bug killer down the gaps between concrete and brick as a short-term fix.

Comment: I would go with ants and get an exterminator in there right away that is a huge amount of material, I know ants will take the dead out with the debris that’s how they identified the type on houses I have had treated. I know termites do dig but I haven’t seen them bring material out like ants.

Comment: 2 words: boric acid.

Comment: "[According to](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:41094616) information in literature boric acid is a weak Lewis acid that has no effect on concrete. Reaction between calcium hydroxide existing in concrete and boric acid [...] is reasonably harmless." - [Boric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid#Insecticidal), "registered in the US as an insecticide ... of cockroaches, termites, fire ants, fleas, silverfish, and many other insects. The product is generally considered to be safe to use in household kitchens to control cockroaches and ants."

Comment: @EdBeal what would be the consequence of leaving it like this? What damage can ants do?

Comment: Believe it or not ants can be extremely destructive in there building. The Pacific Northwest has carpenter ants, we once were buying a house to update and 1 wall several stud bays were only held together by the exterior siding the ants turned the studs into Swiss cheese. My sister in law passed last year and down at the barn just inside a wall my son stepped through the floor these did not look like carpenter ants smaller but they had built a nest about 3’ across under the supporting pier block the floor collapsed because the ant nest was much deeper than wide that we could see and some bite.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Steve. Ants for sure, **maybe pavement ants**. You can find several pesticides at DO MY OWN PEST CONTROL. I worked in pest control for 17 years. A Termiticide / Pesticide called *Termidor SC* will get rid of them for sure. Kinda pricey but it's a concentrate.

You'll probably pay more for a pest control company to do it. Do it yourself. One Ounce per Gallon of water mix should do it.  Just follow the label instructions on the bottle.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Some formatting, proper capitalization and not shouting would be welcome additions to this answer! Feel free to [edit] your post to fix things up. Also, it appears that you're promoting a web site and/or product. It would be great to mention if you're affiliated with either - it's fine if you are, just let us know. Otherwise, this may get flagged as spam.

Comment: Woody, I have a friend that used a special “licensed only” ant killer in the Pacific Northwest. It lasted ~10 years and killed all ants in ground and on wood. Do you know the name it really worked and may not be legal any longer as that was a few years back. I had spent a lot in that area trying to kill carpenter ants and that was the only thing that worked 100% on multiple houses I remodeled and owned. My friend retired and moved and I can’t find him to ask.